# How do I find the angle $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

This is the equation:

$$\sin\theta=0.8\theta$$

Comment: If [Wolfram Alpha's solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+:+sin(x)%3D0.8x) is any indication, $\theta = 0$ is the only exact solution you could get. The other two solutions would be obtained by approximation.

Answer (score 2):

This equation being transcendental, it will not show analytical solutions and numerical methods are required.

You could approximate the solution using 
the approximation $$\sin(\theta) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -\theta) \theta}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -\theta) \theta}\qquad (0\leq \theta\leq\pi)$$ was proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

Using whole numbers, excluding the trivial solution, you will need to solve for $\theta$
$$4 \theta ^2+(20-4 \pi)  \theta  -5 \pi (4- \pi)=0$$ giving as *approximate* acceptable solution
$$\theta_\pm=\pm\frac{1}{8} \left(-20+4 \pi +\sqrt{400+160 \pi -64 \pi ^2}\right)\approx \pm 1.12856$$ while the exact solution would be $1.13110$.

**Edit** *for the fun of it !*

If, graphing, you notice that the solution is close to $\frac \pi 3$, you could build the $[1,n]$ Padé approximants of the function and get as *approximate* solutions
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \theta &  \theta \approx \\
 0 & \frac{5}{9} \left(3 \sqrt{3}-\pi \right) & 1.14142 \\
 1 & \frac{5 \left(54+9 \sqrt{3} \pi -8 \pi ^2\right)}{3 \left(93 \sqrt{3}-40
   \pi \right)} & 1.13014 \\
 2 & \frac{5 \left(-7533 \sqrt{3}+3861 \pi +96 \sqrt{3} \pi ^2-64 \pi
   ^3\right)}{3 \left(-16983+3360 \sqrt{3} \pi -320 \pi ^2\right)} & 1.13118
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using @b00n heT's idea of solving a  biquadratic equation, let us use the $[5,4]$ Padé approximant of $\sin(x)$ built at $x=0$; it is
$$\sin(x)=\frac{x-\frac{53 }{396}x^3+\frac{551 }{166320}x^5} {1+\frac{13 }{396}x^2+\frac{5 }{11088} x^4}$$ The difference between this expression and the usual Taylor series is only $\frac{11 x^{11}}{457228800}$.

So, we now need to solve for $x^2$ the  biquadratic equation
$$491 x^4-26628 x^2+33264=0 \implies x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{6}{491} \left(2219-\sqrt{4470277}\right)}$$ which is $1.13110282$ while the exact solution would be
                                  $1.13110259$

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there are three solutions:

[image]

Clearly $\theta = 0$ is a solution.  By the antisymmetry of the component functions we know there are two symmetric solutions.  Simple numerical solution by computer gives the other two:  $\theta = \pm 1.13.$

Comment: My goodness... a downvote!  Given that the non-zero solution must be found numerically, what more from a solution could you ask for?  The OP asks how to find $\theta$ and my solution explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor's series up to the third term one gets the approximate polynomial equation:
$$\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{6}+\frac{\theta^5}{120}=\frac{4}{5}\theta$$
from which we obtain
$$\theta\cdot \left(24-20\cdot \theta^2+\theta^4\right)=0$$
which has the solution $\theta=0$ and the two solutions to the biquadratic equation
$$\theta^2=\frac{20\pm\sqrt{304}}{2}$$
from which we get 
$$\theta=\pm\sqrt{\frac{20-\sqrt{304}}{2}}\cong \pm 1.132343637293314$$

**Comment**: I included only the first three terms in order to get a biquadratic. Otherwise I would have got a polynomial equation of degree 3, which is harder to deal with. Moreover, the approximation works quite well because we know (a priori) that the solution is not too big, as it can be at most $1/0.8=1.25$.

Comment: You gave me the idea of working another biquadratic equation ! Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: You are welcome! Interesting answer using Padé approximants: I don't know much about those but I know that their convergence is much faster than usual Taylor series, as your solution shows. Have a nice day

Comment: It is a fascinating world (I felt in love with them 60 years ago). On this site, search for *Pade* : there are 476 entries. They are simple to build and an $[m,n]$ Pade approximant is at least equivalent to a $O(x^{m+n+1}$ Taylor expansion.